# How to centre Progress Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

It is centred horizontal not vertical. I've tried other solutions on here and it doesn't seem to work. Can someone explain how I can fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Relative Layout for parent and centerInParent for progressbar ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to the `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity

> Specifies how an object should position its content, on both the X and Y axes, within its own bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1) Add `android:gravity="center"` (or just `center_vertical) to the`LinearLayout`.

2) Use a `RelativeLayout` and set use the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` attribute.

With either option, you can remove the `android:layout_gravity` attribute from the `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"  >

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

for Linear Layout it's:- `android:gravity="center"`

for relative layout it's:- `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`